# compare two files in python ignore comparing commented lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below test files

testfile1 output:

```
   put returns between paragraphs
   for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
   indent code by 4 spaces
```

testfile2 output:

```
   put returns between paragraphs
   for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
   indent code by 4 spaces
   #commented out
```

I want to compare two files  and print only difference output. If any comments in start of line ignore to compare those line.

Below is code i tried:

```
import difflib

with open('testfile1') as text1, open('testfile2') as text2:
    diff = difflib.ndiff(text1.readlines(), text2.readlines())
with open('diff.txt', 'w') as result:
    for line in diff:
        result.write(line)
```

output:

```
 put returns between paragraphs
 for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
 indent code by 4 spaces
+ #commented
```

Expected output:

```
 put returns between paragraphs
 for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
 indent code by 4 spaces
```

and  print "No changes"

Comment: you can check for first character of particular line, is it '#' or not?

Comment: yes check startswith with # if it has # ignore it to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would eliminate the `#`-marked lines using a list comprehension:

```
...
with open('testfile1') as text1, open('testfile2') as text2:
    diff = difflib.ndiff(
        [line for line in text1 if not line.startswith('#')],
        [line for line in text2 if not line.startswith('#')]
        )
...
```

Comment: Great It works, Is there way we can find True or False. If difference between files True and If no difference files False

Comment: Yes, but you don't need `difflib` for that. Just compare the two lists for equality. E.g. `if [line for line in text1 if not line.startswith('#')] == [line for line in text2 if not line.startswith('#')]: ...`